# [Android][Encryption]How to avoid using string while declaring type of enryption

Tags: android, encryption, bouncycastle

I am using BouncyCastle for encryption/decryption. Is there any way to avoid `Cipher.getInstance("RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding")`? I want to prevent attacker of knowing which algorithms I am using. I am trying with something like this:

```
AsymmetricBlockCipher cipher = new PKCS1Encoding(new RSAEngine());
cipher.init(true, publicKey);
```

but i don't know if I am on right track.

Comment: And what would be the difference? The java's code is readable in the same way as string

Comment: I could use obfuscation for Java code, but I can't do the same for string.

Comment: It will ot help as you can't obfuscate runtime library calls the obfuscation works only with your code(and included library) but calls to runtime would not be obfuscated (so fx you have class with method like `Utils.encrypt()` and it will become `a.a()` but in method body there still would be `new PKCS1Encoding(new RSAEngine());` ... anyway proffesional obfuscators encrypt strings, too ...

Comment: may I ask you which verion of BC is used? I read that it is totally replaced by SpongyCastle, is it true?

Comment: I am using version 1.5. What difference would it be if it was replaced with SpongyCastle, or if I would use SpongyCastle as a lib instead of using BC?

Answer (score 1):

Security does not depend on hiding the method and that is why the method can specified with a string and still be secure. For encryption the secrecy is entirely based on the key.

Because of that it is important to use a good key, either random data or if a password is used derived from the password with PBKDF2.

Comment: I am aware of that, but I have requirement to avoid strings like this "RSA/ECB/PKCS1Padding" in my source code.

Comment: Unfortunately uninformed people sometines make inflexible rules that are in some situations are unworkable.